# Connecting csv web feed to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, web-services, csv, wsdl

We have a web feed CSV file on our company's website and I would like to be able to import into it on a daily basis. I can certainly save it as a .txt file and import it, however, I would prefer to have it connected to my SQL Server database and import directly into it without having to download it to a .txt file first.

I have SQL Server Integrated Services but am not sure which method to use. So far it looks like creating a Web Service is the best route but I am unfamiliar with creating a WSDL file.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are comfortable with it, I'd use Python.

Comment: I've never used it before, however, with Visual Studio and Stack Overflow, I might just be able to stumble through it.  :-)

Comment: Download Anaconda, get pymssql and start gorking it out. There are tons of resources available here and online.